# Is this implementation a composition or aggregation?

Tags: java, associations, uml

I am confused to distinguish composition and aggregation from code. For example, from the following code, which part of code indicates their relationship?

```
public class Account {
   private Owner owner;

   public Account(Owner owner) {
      this.owner = owner;
   }
}

public Owner {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a relationship is an aggregation or a composition is a choice you make in design.

It is common with this sort of relation for an `Owner` object to be (or perhaps have) either an aggregation or a composition of multiple `Account` objects, and the distinction is whether deletion of an `Owner` object forces the deletion of its `Account` objects, i.e., whether the lifetime of the `Account` objects is dependent on the lifetime of the owning `Owner` object.

It's also common for an `Account` object to have a link back to its owning `Owner` object as in your code, but I think most people would not regard that link as a either a composition or an aggregation.  It's nice in that case for the `Owner` object to actually be a composition of `Account` objects, and that the field `owner` in `Account` is not allowed to be null.  But it's not necessarily so.  Your choice...

What happens in the "real world" is irrelevant.  What really matters is how *you* choose to model it.

Comment: Hmm. Item references to container, and it CAN be a composition? Too bad! Composition supposes that the life of item is limited by the life  of container and association. It is NOT the case!

Comment: If the item references the container via a non-nullable field, then you have to delete the item before deleting the container, so item's life is indeed dictated by the life of the container.  The item is not in fact a composite of the container...  It would be nice if all these words specified direction more clearly.

Comment: In UML standard "navigation" (I hope I understood you correctly and you mean it) is explicitly described as non-strictly-defined thingie. And it has sense - for the use of class diagrams is not limited to programming only. We could describe so a formal document, and navigational arrows will mean references. Too strict definition would limit the usability. There is a strict "sister" of arrow - that dot on the association end.

Comment: About container life-dependent on items. Yes, it can be as you describe. But I can imagine it to work only in 1-to-1 association. How could you include an instance lifetime simultaneously in lifetimes of several different instances of other classes? And 1-1 asssociation is not a composition, according to standard. Personally, I don't like this limit and don't understand the sense of it, and won't limit myself by it, but it would be not honest to give advices not up to standard and keep mum about this fact.

Answer (score 2):

- There are three kinds of aggregation - none, shared and composed.
- The composed aggregation, or composition is defined strictly in UML standard - when the life of the item instance is limited by life of container or association, it IS composition. So, it could be your case? But the composition also, according to standard, supposes association multiplicities one-to many (1 on one end, 0..* on the other one), and you haven't it here! And you are addressing container from the item, it is impossible for composition!
- Shared aggregation is not defined strictly. Usually it is about one class having instances of another one. But it is not a **rule**, merely a tradition. And you have this case. Sou, you CAN name it shared aggregation. But you needn't.

  - (Often `shared aggregation` is named simply `aggregation`, but it is simply an error. For shortening you can name it `shared`.)
- None aggregation is used when you have no composition and you have decided that you have no shared aggregation. So, you can use it, too.

So, what you have can be named as shared aggregation or none aggregation (the latter the better). But you have one more possibility. What you have here, is the `classifier owned end`. When one class has instance(s) of another one by reference or directly. In UML standard it is also named `atribute`. And is shown as dotted end.

Also, you have rights not to show navigation arrows, dots, multiplicity and aggregation. (you have no obligation to show ALL possible info on the diagram - such lightest form of the class diagram is usually the start variant)

So , you can use the following variants:

[image]

On the right side you can use empty diamond, arrow, dot, or any combination of them. The B variant is the best, IMHO. And C is OK, too.

You can call your association shared aggregation or none aggregation. 
You should call your association a classifier owned/dotted one.

Comment: +1 - good explanation, and a better choice of language than is common.

Comment: @DonRoby Thank you for your appreciation, I am merely citing the UML standard.

Answer (score 1):

Its a Composition, As your `Account` object must have an `owner` associated with it.

If you will allow your Account object creation without any owner associated with it then its a aggregation.

But as per common business logic, it may be always desirable to exist an Account with an owner. An account without an owner will have no sense.

Composition is stricter version of Aggregation. Aggregation simply states "has a" but you can think of Composition as stricter or must to have to create an object (in your case `Account` object)

Comment: But when an Account is destroyed, the associate Owner's detail can still exists, which confused me that if it really a composition.

Comment: @user3143433 The question here would be whether an Account can exist without an owner? Further, in larger picture, what would be the meaning of an owner till the time he doesn't have anything for him to own? will you still call it an owner?

Comment: but the owner may have different type of accounts, if one of them is destroyed, the owner's detail still exist since he still has other accounts

Comment: @user3143433 you are confusing it with relationships, Account to Owner is Composition and one-to-one relationship, however owner to account is a one to many relationship. And an owner needs at least one account associated with him to be called as owner.

Comment: @sakura Account to owner is NOT a composition, because Owner is referenced from Account. Your sentence "Account to Owner is ... one-to-one relationship, however owner to account is a one to many relationship" should be edited somehow - it has no sense now, sorry.

Comment: @Gangnus "Account to owner is NOT a composition, because Owner is referenced from Account." what about other side of it, Account needs an Owner to exist. does it matter or not?

Comment: @sakura If User instance will have its Account instancess and not vice versa, it would be composition, yes. But here in code in question is set, that Account has User.

Comment: @Gangnus If you will read the comments of OP, here the navigability is bi-directional i.e. Account has a owner and owner must have at least one account to be called as owner.

Comment: @sakura Reading comments to the post, I found no info from questioner supporting the thesis that Owner has reference to Account. If you think that the question should be corrected, you should ask the questioner to do it, and better, please, try this in comments under the question.

Comment: @Gangnus "but the owner may have different type of accounts, if one of them is destroyed, the owner's detail still exist since he still has other accounts" I was talking about this comment in my answer post.

Comment: @sakura Oh, yes, sorry, I thought it was yours. My error. Of course, this turns the navigability and dependence other way round. This way, a User can have a composition of accounts. But the question remains unchanged ...